# CSS Liquid horizontal list

Tags: html, css

Ok, I will try to clarify:

I have a set 6 sentences of 3 to 6 words, eg:

```
Some text like this  - Some text like this  - Some text like this  - Some text like this  - Some text like this
```

This is a 100% width centered container.

The site I am working on is using liquid widths for content, so, at smaller resolutions I want the text to wrap.  When I say 'wrap', at smaller resolutions I want it to look like this:

```
some some some some some some 
text text text text text text 
like like like like like like 
this this this this this this
```

so I want the text to wrap like a paragraph of text would wrap in a % width div.

I **dont** want the text to appear like this:

```
Some
text
like
this

Some
text
like
this

Some
text
like
this
```

Hopefully this makes more sense?

Thanks

=====edit===============

I have been trying for the last couple of hours to try and achieve this and I'm about to give up.

It seems fairly simple but I just can't achieve the desired effect and I'm starting to wonder if it's actually possible.

Basically, I have liquid site layout and I want to have a centered horizontal list of text the wraps for different resolutions:

[image]

As you can see from the attached image, when the browser is at larger resolutions I want the text centered but at lower resolutions to wrap properly (each line wraps, not each block of text).

I have tried various things; `display: inline`, `display: block`, floats etc but I just can't get the desired result.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: What's the HTML structure of your content? Are you using media queries?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  Does your list have to be flexible in the number of elements? If so, then I believe that it cannot be done purely in css.  Rather, you would have to have some javascript (jQuery) run after it loads and set the widths of the li elements.

Comment: Thanks, nope it will just be 6 single sentences.

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
   <ul>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
    <li>text</li>
   </ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
overflow:hidden;
width:100%;
}
li {
white-space:nowrap;
float:left;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I think you misunderstood what I meant. At lower resolutions, I want the text all to remain on the same line but the sentences to wrap if to long.  Does this make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe:

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .margin{width:2%; float:left;}
        .column {width:16%; float:left; text-align:center;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="margin">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
        <div class="column">Some text like this</div>
    <div class="margin">&nbsp;</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  Exactly what I was looking for.  I knew it was simple, just couldn't get my around it.  Thanks again.

Comment: One thing, is it possible to have an even space between each block of text?  Would I need to play around with the individual widths of each column?

Comment: Maybe try setting padding:0 5px; on the column class.